# Switch gets on loop with setChecked

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a switch that sends a SMS.

- if disabled, sends an enable SMS
- if enabled, sends a disable SMS

Before sending this SMS, an alertDialog appears to request the user to confirm that wants to make the change.

If the user selects "OK", then the message is send and the alertDialog dissmissed.

If the user selects "No", the alertDialog is dissmissed. But the switch has changed it's state previously, so it should return to the previous state. The only way that I know to do this is to use `switch.setChecked(boolean)`, the problem is that if I use this, the switch gets into a loop and shows me all the time the alertDialog with the enabling or dissabling option.

This is the code:

```
    switch_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                new_state = 1;
            }else {
                new_state = 0;
            }
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.btncancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if (new_state == 1) {
                        new_state = 0;
                        switch_1.setChecked(false);
                    }else {
                        new_state = 1;
                        switch_1.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btnaccept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).sendCommand(new_state);
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });
```

This code is inside a fragment. So basically I would like to know how to return the switch to it's previous state if the user hits the negative button, without getting into this loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because when you call the `setChecked` method, you are also invoking the `onCheckedChanged` `listener`.

To avoid the loop, add another helper `boolean`:

```
boolean isAutomaticallyChanged = false;
```

Once you are changing the state of the `switch` programmatically, add this code: `isAutomaticallyChanged = true;`

finally add in your `listener` code this:

```
if(isAutomaticallyChanged){
  isAutomaticallyChanged = false;
  return;
}
```

So the program won't run the full method when you are changing the value of the switch programmatically.

Hope this helps

**I'll add your edited code here**

```
boolean isAutomaticallyChanged = false;
switch_1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
         if(isAutomaticallyChanged){
           isAutomaticallyChanged = false;
           return;
         }
        if (isChecked) {
            new_state = 1;
        }else {
            new_state = 0;
        }
        AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.btncancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (new_state == 1) {
                    new_state = 0;
                    isAutomaticallyChanged = true;
                    switch_1.setChecked(false);

                }else {
                    new_state = 1;
                    isAutomaticallyChanged = true;
                    switch_1.setChecked(true);
                }
            }
        });
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.btnaccept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                ((MainActivity)getActivity()).sendCommand(new_state);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
});
```